# Alert on VPN Gateway tunnels status

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, site-to-site-vpn, google-cloud-vpn

We have multiple VPN Gateways and Tunnels setup in GCP.

Is there a way to monitor the health of the Tunnels and get alerts when a Tunnel goes down or gets out of sync.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0):

As said on the this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/viewing-logs-metrics#metrics) , you can configure Stackdriver for logging and monitoring, for monitoring (as an example) as said, you can do:

- Go to Stackdriver in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
- Select Dashboards > Create Dashboard.
- Click on Add Chart.
- Give the chart a title.
- Select metrics and filters. For metrics, the resource type is Cloud VPN Gateway.
- Click Save.

You can also see what each metric means in [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/viewing-logs-metrics#monitoring_metrics_for)